# Python regex return all symbols between two types of brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all matches for symbols in between two types of brackets: {}, []. So, the match for the string: "N[SP]K[LKO]{KOP}OP" is N, K, O, P. The brackets are not supposed to be nested.

The current version I wrote is 
`re.compile("^(?!\{\[)?([A-Za-z]+)")`

For the string above, it will return only "N". Can you please help me out?

Comment: I guess you need to tell us just a little bit more. Try to convert your question to a [Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the brackets are always correct (i.e. your string will never have unpaired brackets like `A}B`), you can use the following regex:

```
\w(?=[^[\]{}]*(?:[\[{]|\Z))
```

Explanation:

```
\w             # match a letter
(?=            # positive lookahead: assert that there's...
    [^[\]{}]*  # ...any number of non-bracket characters
    (?:        # ...followed by either...
        [\[{]  # an opening bracket [ or {
    |          # or...
        \Z     # the end of the string
    )
)
```

This is a simple way to check if the matched character is inside brackets or not. If the next bracket character is an opening bracket like `[` or `{`, then the character is *not* enclosed in brackets and will be matched. But if the next bracket character is a closing bracket like `]` or `}`, then we can assume that the character is enclosed in brackets and should not be matched.

Usage and output:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w(?=[^[\]{}]*(?:[\[{]|\Z))', 'N[SP]K[LKO]{KOP}OP')
['N', 'K', 'O', 'P']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect solution for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop off all bracketed things rather than match others.

```
import re


s = 'N[SP]K[LKO]{KOP}OP'
result = re.sub('\[[^]]*?\]|\{[^}]*?\}', '', s)
print result
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to keep compile function, but your solution also works.